# How to push response of an post API into an array using pipe and map operator in angular . It shows [object Object]

Tags: angular, local-storage, pipe, rxjs-pipeable-operators, angular-maps

**I am working on a project where in my component.ts file I am calling a post API which is giving me a response in the format**

```
 email: string,
  employeeAddress: string,
  employeeId: string,
employeeLevel: string
```

**I am not sure whether my approach is correct or not but here is**
**my API calling code**

```
 return this.http.post<{[employeeId : string] : Create}>('http://localhost:9900/api/v1/employee',postData).
    pipe(map(response => {
      var res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response))
        const getCreateempIdArray : any = [] ;
       
       console.log(res)
        for(const employeeId in res){
          if(res.hasOwnProperty(employeeId)){
            getCreateempIdArray.push({ ...res[employeeId]});
            }
           if(res.hasOwnProperty(email)){
             getCreateempIdArray .push({...res[email]});
           } 
        }
        console.log("Employee Id Array from Create employee Service " + getCreateempIdArray)
        return getCreateempIdArray;
      })).
   
  
     subscribe((responseData)=>
    {
       console.log(response)
      
      })
```

**Now the thing I want is that when I get my response then I want to push my employeeId and email corresponding to that employeeId in an array so that I can save the array in local storage and I can get the particular employee email through employeeId by the help of this array.**

**But when I do console.log(getCreateempIdArray) it gives me [object Object]**

**I just want to push the employeeId and its corresponding emailId which I am getting from response body into an array**

Comment: is your response an array of objects or a single object that contains email,employeeAddress,employeeId,employeeLevel? why are you using for loop?

Answer (score 0):

It is shown in the form [object Object] because you are concatenating a string with an object (using ' ' +) and automatically the object is converted to a string.

try this way:

```
console.log("Employee Id Array from Create employee Service ", getCreateempIdArray)
```

Instead of using a (+), use a comma (,) to separate the string and the object.